# Parsing a JSON dictionary with unknown values

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to deal with a dictionary in JSON, looks like following:

```
{
    "Parameters": {
        "IP": "192.168.1.40",
        "TIMEOUT": 900,
        "mode": 0
    },

    "Device": {
        "sector01": {
            "nodes": ["node01", "node02"] 
        },
        "sector02": {
            "nodes": ["node01"]
        },
        "sector03": {
            "nodes": ["node01","node02","node03"]       
        }
    }
}
```

Assume I have no info about the how many sectors and nodes are present and I want to know the number of sectors (and how many nodes per sector).
I was able to find the total no of sectors by :

```
len(data["Device"])
```

But, the total no of nodes per sector is more important in my case.

Comment: So you want to sum over the length of the nodes value for each map in Device? What's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: This looks like just a lack of understanding of how dictionaries work. Try: `len(data["Device"]["sector03"]["nodes"])`

Comment: use `for-loop` to get sector (one-by-one) and you don't have to know how many stectors you have - and then you can get `"nodes"` in sector to check its `len()`

Comment: `for key, val in data['Device'].items(): print(key, len(val["nodes"]))`

Comment: @furas I was trying to use key() but your line worked like a charm, thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for-loop` to get every "sector" (it doesn't matter how many you have sectors) and then you can get "nodes" in sector and check `len()`

```
for key, val in data['Device'].items(): 
    print(key, len(val["nodes"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

your_json = """{
        "Parameters": {
            "IP": "192.168.1.40",
            "TIMEOUT": 900,
            "mode": 0
        },

        "Device": {
            "sector01": {
                "nodes": ["node01", "node02"] 
            },
            "sector02": {
                "nodes": ["node01"]
            },
            "sector03": {
                "nodes": ["node01","node02","node03"]       
            }
        }
    }"""

your_dict = json.loads(your_json)
len_of_device = len(your_dict['Device'])
dict_len_of_sectors = {}
for key in your_dict['Device']:
    dict_len_of_sectors[key] = len(your_dict['Device'][key]['nodes'])

print(str(dict_len_of_sectors))
```

I suggest study more here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict